# Odd behavior in boost::format hex

Tags: c++, boost, format, hex, boost-format

I'm trying to format a binary array: `char* memblock` to a hex string.

When I use the following:

```
fprintf(out, "0x%02x,", memblock[0]);
```

I get the following output:

```
0x7f,
```

When I try to use `boost::format` on an ofstream like so:

```
std::ofstream outFile (path, std::ios::out); //also tried with binary
outFile << (boost::format("0x%02x")%memblock[0]);
```

I get a weird output like this (seen in Vi): `0x0^?`.

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that the *character* for `0x7f` is <kbd>CTRL-?</kbd>, it looks like it's outputting the `memblock[0]` as a character rather than a hex value, despite your format string.

This actually makes sense based on what I've read in the documentation. `Boost::format` is a type-safe library where the format specifiers dictate how a variable will be output, *but limited by the actual type of said variable,* which takes precedence.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#syntax) states (my bold):

> Legacy printf format strings: `%spec` where `spec` is a `printf` format specification.
>
> `spec` passes formatting options, like width, alignment, numerical base used for formatting numbers, as well as other specific flags. But the classical type-specification flag of `printf` has **a weaker meaning** in format.
>
> It merely **sets the appropriate flags** on the internal stream, and/or formatting parameters, but **does not require the corresponding argument to be of a specific type.** e.g. : the specification `2$x`, meaning "print argument number 2, which is an integral number, in hexa" for printf, merely means "print argument 2 with stream basefield flags set to hex" for format.

And presumably, having the field flag set to hex doesn't make a lot of sense when you're printing a `char`, so it's ignored. Additionally from that documentation (though paraphrased a little):

> The `type-char` does not **impose** the concerned argument to be of a restricted set of types, but **merely sets the flags** that are associated with this type specification. A `type-char` of `p` or `x` means hexadecimal output but simply sets the hex flag on the stream.

This is also verified more specifically by the text from [this link](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Format-format-strings-and-character-types-td2575140.html):

> My colleagues and I have found, though, that when a `%d` descriptor is used to print a `char` variable the result is as though a `%c` descriptor had been used - `printf` and `boost::format` don't produce the same result.

The Boost documentation linked to above also explains that the zero-padding `0` modifier works on *all* types, not just integral ones, which is why you're getting the second `0` in `0x0^?` (the `^?` is a *single* character).

---

In many ways, this is similar to the problem of trying to output a `const char *` in C++ so that you see a *pointer.* The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   const char *xyzzy = "plugh";
   std::cout << xyzzy << '\n';
   std::cout << (void*)xyzzy << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

will produce something like:

```
plugh
0x4009a0
```

because the standard libraries know that C-style strings are a special case but, if you *tell* them it's a void pointer, they'll give you a pointer as output.

A solution in *your* specific case may be just to cast your `char` to an `int` or some other type that intelligently handles the `%x` format specifier:

```
outFile << (boost::format("0x%02x") % static_cast<int>(memblock[0]));
```

Comment: Wow. This is incredibly confusing and really ought to be explained and highlighted in the docs themselves. I couldn't find anything indicating how `char` would be handled by `boost::format`.